# how to set angularjs as the view engine for expressjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have created a express project.  Express has set jade as the default view engine in app.js which looks like this:

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

I want to instead use angularjs as my view engine.  Do I set this in the app.js and if so, what is the syntax.  Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: angular runs in client, not server at least angular 1

Comment: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Answer (score 1):

> For every route you render the same page with a different route view in angularjs. Here i have set ejs as default render engine.

```
//server side
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

router.get('/dashboard', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

//client side
app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider',
function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
        .state('auth',{
            url:'/',
            templateUrl: 'app/layouts/a.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        })
        .state('app',{
            url:'/dashboard',
            templateUrl:'app/layouts/b.html',
            controller: 'MainController'
        });
}]);
```